# have to display some message if no any radio button is selected and submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display some message without using alert box if `associateID` is `null`.
If possible can we do it using jquery? but I don't know how to write code using jquery.
I want to display message in same page but don't want to use alert box.

```
function retrieveAssociate()
{
    //alert("in retrive associate");
    var associates = document.getElementsByName("resourceId");
    var associateID = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < associates.length; i++) {       
        if (associates[i].checked) {
            associateID = associates[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(associateID==null) {
        //in this part i need to put my logic to display message
        //here i want to display some message without using alert box if associateID is null
        //alert("Please select associate ID");          
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript as implied by jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

you could have some other element in your page. for example if it input text

```
if(associateID==null){

$("#messageinput").val("associateID is null");

}
else{

}
```

or without using jquery

```
if(associateID==null){

var elem = document.getElementById("messageinput");
elem.value = "associateID is null";

    }
    else{

    }
```

make sure you have this in your html body

```
<input type="text" id="messageinput"/>
```

and import necessary jquery version.

first you need to set attribute in servlet like

```
request.setAttribute("message", "some message");
```

for JSTL import

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

in your HTML page you could use the c:out tag

```
<c:out value="${message}"/>
```

make sure you configure your build path and download the jstl jar file

Comment: How can we display some message in between java code using html tag?

Comment: are you using jsp and servlets?php?could you give me some more information

Comment: i am using jsp and servlet

Comment: you can you JSTL(tag libraries) in servlet you could set some messages using requestscope request.setAttribute("message","hello user"); in html import core taglibrary then <c:out value="${message}"/> if you dont want to use JSTL you could you Expression language(EL) ${message} in your html page. i recommend to use JSTL. accept my answer if it is helpful to you

Comment: can we enable 2 submit button on clicking radio button? Initially both submit button are disabled.

Comment: javascript would be responsible in that matters. var button=getElementByID("buttonid"); button.disabled=false/true;

Comment: how can i write jquery to check if userid exists in database or not? suppose i have two field userid and username.. one typing userid it should check in databse and if userid exists then it should display message.. Please help me...

Comment: regarding the database that should be on the server side. on your servlet you could check there your rows from the database.